# Unable to reactivate cancelled MobileMe trial account

Tags: mobileme

I tried MobileMe a while back but never subscribed.  I have since used the same Apple ID to enable Find My iPhone and this works fine.  I log in at me.com and get redirected to me.com/find.  However, no matter what I try there doesn't seem to be a way to reactivate a paid-for MobileMe account.  Am I missing something?

The support sites tell me to go to me.com/renew, but if I do this I get redirected to me.com/find.  I've checked https://appleid.apple.com and there doesn't seem to be any option for viewing or upgrading my MobileMe details.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That account shouldn't be burned since Apple explicitly [allows for renewal of expired trials](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1062) as part of the normal upgrade process. You will very likely lose your data if it has been expired past 15 days but you shouldn't lose the account if you still know the password and can answer security questions or account history questions if you get to a human for support.

The system is in the middle of a change where they are phasing out physical box with activation codes and moving to all online activations.

If you can't renew it [following this link](http://help.apple.com/mobileme/?lang=eninterface/#mmfc0ef998) then hop on the [Express Lane](https://expresslane.apple.com) and ask for help with Mobile Me billing. You should get connected to someone that can look up your account and see why it might be blocked.

I have had success adding these accounts as a sub-account on a family pack as well, but that involves more money or finding a friend to "resuscitate" your account long enough to renew it as a stand-alone account.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem... I have my apple account ...@gmail.com, and an apple/mobileme account ...@me.com

My trial expired and now I want to subscribed... but no matter what I do I constantly get redirected and cannot renew or enter billing info.. even trying either ...@me.com or ..@gmail.com logins

Why is it so hard to pay you money Apple??

Answer (score -1):

I think if you have never subscribed, as your mobileme account is going to be an actual @me.com address,that you would need to actually sign up an account for the first time.

Comment: If I try and sign up for a new account it tells me my member name has already been taken, which is from my existing account.  I just need to upgrade my free account but can't see how.

Comment: Apple explicitly allows renewal of trial Mobile Me memberships. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1062

Comment: Yep I am aware, I just assumed it wasn't an actual trial as he said he didn't see the reactivate link. My mistake.